# Have a Button call a UITabBar Application on iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I am making an application that has a UITabBar and it works just fine, however I want to add a first screen which contains some instructions and a logo, then a button and when said button is pressed to show the UITabBar I've tried for a couple of days to do this on my own with no luck, I'm not even sure if it can be done, could anyone help me out? or give me a lead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up the tab bar application, and then showing the first screen over it as a modalViewController. Inside your main app's viewController:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:firstViewController animated:NO];
[firstViewController release];
```

When the button is pressed inside the modal view, call:

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to get rid of it. You can adjust the animation style for the dismissal, or use `NO` instead to have it just disappear.

Comment: If you show the modal view in a ViewController that is part of the tab bar, the tab bar will still be visible. Instead you'll want to add the modal as a subview to your main window in the app delegate, loaded after the tab bar and before [window makeKeyAndVisible];